SwiftUI custom annotations ignores Z-index
I'm using a custom view for Map annotation, basically is something like this:
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: [place]) { place in
    MapAnnotation(coordinate: place.location) {
        view(for: place)
            .zIndex(place.state == .selected ? 100 : 1)
    }
}

Also tried using this other approach that has a binding for the selection, but the selected annotation still not moving to front:
Map(selection: $selected) {
    ForEach(testAnnotations) { annotation in
        Annotation(annotation.titleText ?? "-", coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
            view(for: annotation)
        }
    }
}

In both cases, all the annotations are added and displayed propertly, even the selection is working as expected, however, if the annotations is behind another, still that way. This was working on UIKit, but now is not. I have been serching and looks like is something common, does anyone has any workaround to solve this? Thanks in advance.

I believe the Map(...) constructor has an option to add binding values for the items. Given you're not using a binding, I wouldn't expect it to change the zIndex based on selection. Alternatively, there may be a "Selection" argument as well.

Yeah, I also tried using the binding approach but doesn't worked eater, will update the question, thank you!

You could try using
mapOverlayLevel on the MapAnnotation
instead of .zIndex on the view.

mapOverlayLevel allows you change the z-index of a MapContent.
Map(selection: $selected) {
    ForEach(testAnnotations) { annotation in
        Annotation(annotation.titleText ?? "-", coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
            view(for: annotation)
        }
        .mapOverlayLevel(level: selected == annotation ? .aboveLabels : .aboveRoads)
    }
}

However, this also changes the z-index of the annotation relative to other things on the map, such as roads, labels, etc.
If that is undesirable, another way to change the z-index is to reorder the data source (testAnnotations in this case). The map draws the annotations in the same order as they appear in the MapContentBuilder closure. By moving an element to the very end of testAnnotations, you are effectively moving it to the top.
.onChange(of: selected) { _, newValue in
    if let index = testAnnotations.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == newValue?.id }) {
        testAnnotations.move(fromOffsets: [index], toOffset: testAnnotations.count - 1)
    }
}


Here is a minimal reproducible example:
struct Place: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let color: Color
    
    var id: String { name }
}

@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedPlace: Place?
    
    @State var places = [
        Place(name: "A", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.8902, longitude: 12.4922), color: .red),
        Place(name: "B", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.8986, longitude: 12.4769), color: .green),
        Place(name: "C", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9009, longitude: 12.4833), color: .blue)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(selection: $selectedPlace) {
            ForEach(places) { place in
                Annotation(place.name, coordinate: place.coordinates) {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(place.color)
                        .frame(width: 30)
                }
                .tag(place)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedPlace) { _, newValue in
            if let index = places.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == newValue?.id }) {
                places.move(fromOffsets: [index], toOffset: places.count - 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Hashable {
    public static func ==(lhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D, rhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        lhs.latitude == rhs.latitude && lhs.longitude == rhs.longitude
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(latitude)
        hasher.combine(longitude)
    }
}


Thanks man, I checked your example and worked, hower I saw that even removing the .onChange block, the selected annotation is moved to top! Will check and try to replicate on my code. Thanks again!

This doesn't actually work. The change in pin order is due to the selected item. If the above code is changed and onChange handler are removed, the same behavior remains, so this is unfortunately not the solution. Thanks anyway!
